# how to create dynamic list with quotation mark?

Tags: json, list, flutter, quotation-marks

I created a dynamic list. Like this -

```
  List selectedSubjectNameList = [];
Future addSubjectName(college, subject) async {
    setState(() {
      selectedSubjectNameList.add({"college": college, "subject": subject});
    });
  }
```

After adding item, here is output -

> *{college:  Dhaka Commerce College, subject:  Bangla},*

But I want a output like this. (with quotation mark)

> *{college:  "Dhaka Commerce College", subject:  "Bangla"},*

How can I create this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply your list in `jsonEncode`, Coz it Converts `object` to a JSON `string`.

```
import 'dart:convert';

var listValue = jsonEncode(selectedSubjectNameList);

print(listValue);
```

Comment: Do you know how to add quotation marks without converting json to string?